# How to get combinations of two factors and convert into a new factor in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

For example, I can do something like this:

```
x = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1)
y = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3))
z= ifelse(x==1 & y=="a", "a1", ifelse(x==1 & y=="b", "b1", ifelse(x==2 & y=="a", "a2", ifelse(x==2 & y=="b", "b2", ifelse(x==3 & y=="a", "a3", "b3")))))
z = factor(z)
```

But this is tedious,  is there a better way?

Comment: x is not a factor, so you are not combining two factors in the code above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `paste0` to combine the vectors

```
factor(paste0(y, x))
```

Or

```
factor(paste(y, x, sep=""))
```

Comment: or `interaction(y, x, sep="")`

Answer (score 3):

As stated in a [similar thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-November/178808.html): 
If you have two factors `x` and `y`, the use of

```
interaction(x, y)
```

will produce a new factor as you need. Its levels are all the possible combinations (pairs) of the levels of both factors.